# Find all prime $p$ such that there exists integers $m$ and $n$ satisfying $p=m^2+n^2$ and $p$ divides $m^3+n^3+8mn$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to find all prime $p$ such that there exists integers $m$ and $n$ satisfying $p=m^2+n^2$ and $p$ divides $m^3+n^3+8mn$.

This is a tough question in my opinion as I have been trying for some time on it. I was able to identify gcd $m$ and $n$ as $1$ but couldn't continue. I have an idea of trying to factor $m^3+n^3+8mn$ but can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p \mid (m^2+n^2)(m+n)=m^3+n^3+m^2n+n^2m$ and $p \mid n^3+8mn+m^3$ then $p \mid m^2n+n^2m-8mn$ i.e. $p \mid n+m-8$. From here notice that it implies $|n+m-8|\ge|p|=n^2+m^2$ and this inequality is not satisfied for many values of $n$ and $m$. For these values you only need to check if the divisibility indeed holds.